# Ionic 3 with iscroll

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, iscroll

I"m trying to make [iscroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) work with [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/).

1. I installed the iscroll package using:

   ```
   npm install iscroll --save
   ```

as the result, iscroll subfolder was added into the node_modules folder

2. I installed `@types/iscroll` using:

   ```
   npm install @types/iscroll --save
   ```

as the result, iscroll subfolder was added into the `node_modules/@types` folder

3. I can import iscroll and use it in the code like:

```js
import 'iscroll';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  iScroll: IScroll;
    
  ngOnInit(){
   this.iScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper');
  }
}
```

4. I run

   ```
   ionic serve
   ```

It does not work!

It starts working only when I add a script tag in my index.html, like:

```html
<script src="assets/dist/iscroll.js"></script>
```

The problem is: in the case when I have the script tag, I have duplicates in www folder: one "version" of the script is stored inside assest/dist folder and another "version" (which looks the same) is stored inside vendor.js.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { IScroll } from 'iscroll';`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, thank you for the idea, but if I do like you said, I have "@types/iscroll/index.d.ts" is not a module.It sounds logical, I do not see the statements to declare a module: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/iscroll/index.d.ts